# Updating a service reference with modified casing in url doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, updates, service-reference

When I try to update a service reference in Visual Studio from

https://[host]/Services/channel/getBusinessPartnerList/1.0?wsdl

to (mind the casing difference)

https://[host]/Services/Channel/GetBusinessPartnerList/1.0?wsdl

Visual studio seems to select a previous chosen url, so this fails since the target host server uses case sensitive urls

I tried

- to add a random url parameter, but the server is not happy with that
- remove all old service configurations pointing to the "old" end point
- restart visual studio after cleaning out the "old" service reference

But the old url keeps being chosen over the new url.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I bypassed this issue by reverting to the old version and do a find and replace (matching case) of the old urls to the new urls in the generated files.

Maybe it could help someone who encounters this issue too.